# Forecast Multiple output for N days using LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am trying to create a LSTM model that can take multiple input features and Forecast those multiple features for N days

Eg I want to give 4 Features as input for 103 days not I want to forecast those 4 features for next 5 days

input features = [A1,B1,C1,D1],[A2,B2,C2,D2],....,  [A103,B103,C103,D103]
output = [A104,B104,C104,D105],...,[A109,B109,C109,D109]

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(data)

train = scaled_data[:13813,:]
test = scaled_data[13813:,:]

def create_dataset(dataset,size):
    X = []
    y = []
    for i in range(len(dataset)-size-1):
        a = dataset[i:(i+size),:]
        a = dataset[i:(i+size),:]
        X.append(a)
        y.append(dataset[i+size])
    return np.array(X),np.array(y)
##535 is number of data i want to use to forecast the feature

X_test, y_test = create_dataset(test,535)
X_train,y_train = create_dataset(train,535)

##X_train and y_train shape  ((13277, 535, 17), (13277, 17))
##X_test and y_test shape  ((2917, 535, 17), (2917, 17))


model_2 = Sequential()
model_2.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=128,return_sequences=True,input_shape = (X_train.shape[1],17)))
model_2.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=64,return_sequences=True))
model_2.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=50,return_sequences=True))
model_2.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=32))
model_2.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=17,activation='linear'))
model_2.summary()    

model_2.compile(loss='MSE',optimizer='adam')
model_history_2 = model_2.fit(X_train,y_train,validation_data=(X_test,y_test),callbacks=[early_stopping],epochs = 5,batch_size=150)

##But after this I am unable understand how to create a sliding window to predict the next 103 records.
```